# Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer"

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, shading, undefined

I am writing a slide using Latex beamer documentclass.
I have encountered `**Package pgf Errors**: **Undefined shading** "beamer@barshade", "beamer@aboveframetitle", "beamer@belowframetitle"`.

I have tried the same tex source code in different machine/app, and I have different results:

1) My old Mac Book Pro (MBP) with TexStudio: no error and the generated PDF is correct;

2) My old Mac Book Pro (MBP) with TexShop: also no error and the generated PDF is correct;

3) My new iMAC(just bought in August 2019) with TexStudio: got the above mentioned Package pgf Errors, the PDF can be generated and viewed, with some format/shading missing;

4) My new iMAC with TexShop: got the same error message, but the PDF cannot be generated;

### Here is my Latex source for all these 4 experiments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Setup appearance:
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


% Standard packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\title[Block Partitioning and Perfect Phylogenies] 
{
  Slide Title
}


\author[ABC]
{
  Author 1\inst{1}
}

\institute[XYZ]
{
  \inst{1}%
  The Author is working here
}

\date[WABI 2006]
{Conference XXX, 2019}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Page Title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item AAAAA
  \item BBBBB
  \item CCCC
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

### Here is my iMAC (bad machine) with TexStudio log file (my latex source file name is: Beamer_iMAC_reduce.tex):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.9.13)  14 SEP 2019 23:25
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Beamer_iMAC_reduce.tex
(./Beamer_iMAC_reduce.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box27
\beamer@tempcount=\count81
\c@beamerpauses=\count82

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count83
\beamer@minimum=\count84
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box28
\beamer@modecount=\count85
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)

***..........................................skip many message here..........................................***

No file Beamer_iMAC_reduce.nav.

! Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer@barshade".

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38 \begin{document}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/bx/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 41.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 41.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/it' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/it' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/m/sl' tried instead on input line 41.


! Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer@barshade".

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \end{frame}

(That was another \errmessage.)

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
\openout4 = `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.vrb'.


(./Beamer_iMAC_reduce.vrb)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/bx/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 52.


! Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer@aboveframetitle".

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52 \end{frame}

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer@belowframetitle".

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52 \end{frame}

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgf Error: Undefined shading "beamer@barshade".

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52 \end{frame}

(That was another \errmessage.)

[2

]
\tf@nav=\write6
\openout6 = `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.nav'.

\tf@toc=\write7
\openout7 = `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.toc'.

\tf@snm=\write8
\openout8 = `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.snm'.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 55.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 55.
 (./Beamer_iMAC_reduce.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 55.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 55.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `Beamer_iMAC_reduce.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  4CA0FF56E3EE124326A4720E136735D1;47.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17977 strings out of 492616
 340426 string characters out of 6129481
 428168 words of memory out of 5000000
 21465 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 36742 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,16n,65p,785b,496s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/t
exlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/
2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb>
Output written on Beamer_iMAC_reduce.pdf (2 pages, 16331 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 56 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 34 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 6 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 97 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: well you removed the important part from your log-file, but if I should guess I would say that your pgf version is outdated. So run an update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After executing "tlmgr update --all" in my iMAC's root mode, I can generate the PDF correctly in TexStudio.

You are right, the problem in on the package's old version.

Thank you!